# Django Static image not displaying while using block

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django, I am trying to display the image but I am getting the error.

> Invalid block tag on line 35: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you
>   forget to register or load this tag?

If I added my image directly on index.html page then the image is displaying but when I am using extends and block to display then I am getting the error.

**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

**home.html**

```
  {% extends 'demo1/index.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/web/landing-page.png' %}" alt="Landing Page">
   {% endblock %}
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title%}Home{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

     {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the open `{` in your `home-page`

```
{% extends 'demo1/index.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/web/landing-page.png' %}" alt="Landing Page">
{% endblock %}
```

**NOTE**

Django documentation prefers now `{% load static %}`.
`{% load staticfiles %}`  works but I think it is deprecated.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static

**Update:**

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of "render
>   this subtemplate and include the HTML", not as "parse this subtemplate
>   and include its contents as if it were part of the parent". This means
>   that there is no shared state between included templates -- each
>   include is a completely independent rendering process.

Therefore please also load the `static` file in your home-page too

Comment: thanks for information, I change {% load static %} but still same issue. if I directly add image on my index.html then it's working but not working from the block.

Comment: Yes, If I add {% load static %} on home.html then I am getting the image..but I read somewhere that we can't use {% load static %} on block page.

Comment: Because in {% extends 'demo1/index.html' %} we alredy added {% load static %}. correct?

Comment: @NarendraVerma, according docs again "The extends tag is the key here. It tells the template engine that this template “extends” another template. When the template system evaluates this template, first it locates the parent – in this case, “base.html”." So it locates the parent first and then rendering current template so it needs to check loaded `static`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Do just `{% load static %}` on top of your **home.html** template.

Comment: I removed {% load static from staticfiles %} and added {% load static %} and still same issue.

Comment: You need to have `{% load static %}` in every single template down the chain: so also in home.html (even if it extends index.html that already has it). Also when you `{% include ... %}` another template, that template needs the `{% load static %}` if you use `static` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a brace in your home.html

`{% extends 'demo1/index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<img src="{% static 'images/web/landing-page.png' %}" alt="Landing Page">
% endblock %}`

should be

`{% extends 'demo1/index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<img src="{% static 'images/web/landing-page.png' %}" alt="Landing Page">
{% endblock %}`

Comment: that was typo mistake form my side while formating the code.

Comment: {% static 'images/web/landing-page.png' %} this is not working. I am getting the error.